# Wildcard Paths with semanage fcontext

Tags: linux, selinux

I am trying to set SELinux contexts within a directory structure. So it is something like this:

```
/var/www/sites
    /www.example.com
        /html
        /logs
    /www.example.org
        /html
        /logs
```

I want to set different contexts on all of the `logs` directories and the `html` directories. With `chcon` I can just do:

```
sudo chcon -Rt httpd_sys_rw_content_t /var/www/sites/*/html
sudo chcon -Rt httpd_log_t /var/www/sites/*/logs
```

But now I want to make them permanent and not so easy with `semanage fcontext`. It seems to use regex selection based on the docs, which give examples like `/myweb(/.*)?` repeatedly. So I tried this:

```
sudo semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t "/var/www/sites/[^/]+/html(/.*)?"
```

But it doesn't make any changes. When I use `restorecon` after this nothing has changed. If I don't try to use `[^/]+` it works fine:

```
sudo semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t "/var/www/sites/www.example.com/html(/.*)?"
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Documentation on this is very limited from what I've found so far. How can I use a wildcard selection within a path? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would still like to know if this is possible using the `semanage fcontext` command directly, but I worked out a way to do this using `find`:

```
sudo find /var/www/sites -type d -regex "/var/www/sites/[^/]+/html" -exec semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t '{}(/.*)?' \;
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a bit of documentation on the format of the regular expressions that semanage admits would be helpful, I've discovered some patterns that work only through trial and error.

These patterns have worked for me to specify multiple paths beyond the wildcard to he end:

```
semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t "/var/www/(public/media|httpdocs/wp-content)/uploads(/.*)?"
```

This matches both `public/media/uploads` and `httpdocs/wp-content/uploads` and children.

```
semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t "/var/www/host/httpdocs(/subdir)?/wp-content/uploads(/.*)?"
```

This matches both `httpdocs/wp-content/...` and `httpdocs/eng/wp-content/...`

I'm making this response a wiki hoping others would contribute working patterns to it.

Answer (score 1):

`semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t "/var/www/sites/.*/html(/.*)?"`

You'll see this format being used (on Centos 7 by default) by running `semanage fcontext -l | grep /var/www`